# Generic Array creation and null pointer errors

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have an array of linked list which runs parrallel to an ordered object array. If an extra element is entered into the object array i need to insert an extra element into the same space in the linked list.
I have this method as follows

```
public static LinkedList<User>[] insertElement (LinkedList<User>[]a, int index, User friend) {
  LinkedList<User>[] bp = new LinkedList[nElems];

  for (int i=0; i<index; i++){
     bp[i]=a[i-1];
  }
   //index is the position in which i want to insert a new element
   bp[index].add(friend);

  for (int i=index+1; i<a.length; i++){
    bp[i]=a[-1];
  }
  return bp;
}
```

When `bp` is initialised as shown I get a null pointer error

When it is initialised as:

```
LinkedList<User>[] bp = new LinkedList<User>[nElems];
```

I get a generic array creation error. What it the correct way to initialise this?

Comment: I assume that your attempt to index into a an array in the second `for` loop, `bp[i] = a[-1];`, is a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
LinkedList<User>[] bp = new LinkedList[nElems];
```

..creates an array of null references to `LinkedList<User>`. You must initialize these before you use them:

```
LinkedList<User>[] bp = new LinkedList[nElems];

for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
    bp[i] = new LinkedList<User>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created an array of linked lists, but you haven't created any `LinkedList`s within the array.

You need to create the list in each slot of the array before you try and use it.

It seems unlikely that this is what you are actually trying to do though...you seem to be mixing up `Array`s and `List`s. Really you should use either `Collection`s or `Array`s, not mix the two together.

Answer (score 0):

What I guess you are trying to do is having a ordered List of Users. If this is the case you can do this by just having a `LinkedList` and using

```
LinkedList<String> users = new LinkedList<>();
users.add( index, friend );
```

`LinkedList.add` automatically shifts all elements to the right.